# Electric fields existing everywhere in the universe, communication faster than speed of light?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, speed-of-light, faster-than-light, causality

If I take a charge and oscillate it, does that instantaneously create a field with magnitude, however small, at every point in the universe? If so, couldn't this fact be used to send messages faster than the speed of light? Ie: You stay on earth with the charge and I'll go to the edge of the universe and I'll sense an electric field from your oscillating charge, a message faster than the speed of light.

Comment: If you throw a stone into a lake does the whole lake surface start rippling instantaneously, or do the ripples spread outwards from the impact point at a finite speed?

Comment: Anytime you derive a result that involves faster-than-light travel, perpetual motion, or universally decreasing entropy, there is always an error in the reasoning. Always.

Comment: Please don’t edit a question after you have received answers in a way that invalidates the answers. I have reverted your edits. You should ask a new question instead

Comment: Sorry Dale, i wasn't sure whether to edit my question, use the comment button or 'answer your question' button, the suggestion was that if it was a response to a comment then I should edit the question, but now i know better, i will make another question, deepest apologies.

Answer (score 2):

In practice the *in vacuo* solution of Maxwell's equations propagates of the charge's electromagnetic field as a function of $ckt-\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}$ at speed $c$. Therefore, the behaviour at time $t$ some distance from the charge reflects the charge's behaviour at a somewhat earlier time. @JohnRennie's analogy is a good one, although ironically the mathematics is actually simpler in the case of electromagnetism. In that respect, a closer analogy is to the speed of sound due to the wave equation on a plucked string.

Comment: Also noteworthy that if you could induce forces instantly everywhere by moving a charge in a universe where c is the same for all observers, moving a charge would precede its own cause for half of all possible observers and send information backwards in time for the other half, with only a tiny handful of observers actually observing causality preserving Star Trek style instant communication.

Answer (score 1):

While the *field* exists everywhere, the *excitations* of the field do not- they propagate through the field from their source outwards at a finite (but very large) speed- the speed of light.